Selector to match all similar elements with the same class after an element?
I am trying to get a CSS selector to match the elements with the .disabled class name, but only after the element with .today class name. It should match Day 11, Day 12 & Day 13 elements in below example.
Here is my HTML:
<div class="month">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="day disabled">Day 1</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 2</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 3</div>
    <div class="day today">Day 4</div>
    <div class="day">Day 5</div>
    <div class="day">Day 6</div>
    <div class="day">Day 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="month">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="day">Day 8</div>
    <div class="day">Day 9</div>
    <div class="day">Day 10</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 11</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 12</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 13</div>
    <div class="day">Day 14</div>
  </div>
</div>

I have tried this selector, but it will only work on elements in the same level as .today class:
.today ~ .disabled: {
  background: red
}

Any idea if this can be done?

You could using some version of :has and iterating up the DOM but it would be incredibly brittle.


.week {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: .25em;
}

.month .week .today {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.month:has(.today)~.month .week .disabled {
  background: lightblue;
}
<div class="month">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="day disabled">Day 1</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 2</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 3</div>
    <div class="day today">Day 4</div>
    <div class="day">Day 5</div>
    <div class="day">Day 6</div>
    <div class="day">Day 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="month">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="day">Day 8</div>
    <div class="day">Day 9</div>
    <div class="day">Day 10</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 11</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 12</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 13</div>
    <div class="day">Day 14</div>
  </div>
</div>




You can try this (assuming month elements are always sibling)


.month:has(.today) ~ .month .disabled, /* select the days of the other months */
.today ~ .disabled { /* select the days inside the same month */
  background: red
}
<div class="month">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="day disabled">Day 1</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 2</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 3</div>
    <div class="day today">Day 4</div>
    <div class="day">Day 5</div>
    <div class="day">Day 6</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="month">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="day">Day 8</div>
    <div class="day">Day 9</div>
    <div class="day">Day 10</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 11</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 12</div>
    <div class="day disabled">Day 13</div>
    <div class="day">Day 14</div>
  </div>
</div>




The question does not explicitly state it, but I suppose the current month could have more weeks after the one that contains today, so to cover that as well, you might want to also add .month .week:has(.today) ~ .week .disabled
